# Compare Types in generic function using TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

I am trying to create a Service Repository using TypeScript.

I am trying to determine if a service instance of a specified type has already been registered. Here's an example (lets assume the interfaces exist):

```
class ServiceRepository {
static RegisteredServices: Array<IService> = new Array<IService>();

static Register<T extends IService>(service: T) {
    // Does a registered service already exist?
    var existingService = this.RegisteredServices.filter(
        function (item: IService) {
            return (item instanceof T);   // <--------------------- How do we compare Types?
        });

    if (existingService != null) {
        // Remove it first.
        this.RegisteredServices.splice(this.RegisteredServices.indexOf(existingService), 1);
    }

    // Add new service instance.
    this.RegisteredServices.push(service);
}
```

}

How do I compare the type of Item with the generic type T?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types are erased at runtime in TypeScript. So you need some runtime mechanism not dependent upon the type. Here is one solution that checks the name property on a class :

```
interface IService{}

class ServiceRepository {
    static RegisteredServices: Array<IService> = new Array<IService>();

    static Register<T extends IService>(service: T) {
        // Does a registered service already exist?
        var existingService = this.RegisteredServices.filter(
            function(item: IService) {
                return ((<any>item).name == (<any>service).name); // check
            })[0];

        if (existingService) {
            // Remove it first.
            console.log('removing:',existingService);
            this.RegisteredServices.splice(this.RegisteredServices.indexOf(existingService), 1);
        }

        // Add new service instance.
        this.RegisteredServices.push(service);
    }
}

class Foo implements IService{}
ServiceRepository.Register(Foo);
ServiceRepository.Register(Foo);
```

`name` is a property on named functions and this works because of the way classes are implemented in TypeScript to JavaScript translation.

Plus the result of the filter function is an array. I fixed that for you.

Comment: Thanks basarat, yeah I am getting my head around that now, remembering TypeScript only helps structure the code, eventually it will still be POJS :P

Comment: the first two lines from @basarat's answer are really good to always keep in mind: `Types are erased at runtime in TypeScript.` `So you need some runtime mechanism not dependent upon the type.`